# How to permanently disable hibernation on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, sleep, hibernate, hybrid-sleep

I want to use Wake-On-Lan for my working machine (it is a desktop machine). But it only works when the machine is in S3 (Stand By) state. It won't work in Hibernation or Hybrid Sleep state. So I have to disable hibernation.

First, I use `powercfg /a` to check all the possible sleep states:

```
The following sleep states are available on this system:
    Standby (S3)
    Hibernate
    Hybrid Sleep
    Fast Startup
```

I searched a lot and most methods use below command.

```
powercfg /hibernate off
```

With this command, the hibernation file `hiberfil.sys` is deleted from the `C:\`.

Then I use `powercfg /a` to check all the possible sleep states again:

```
The following sleep states are available on this system:
    Standby (S3)
```

So we can see only Standby remains. This is what I want.

And then I also followed this [link](https://www.vladan.fr/disable-hibernation-on-windows/) to enable below group policy:

> Computer Configuration > Policies > Administrative templates > System > Power Management > Sleep Settings > **Turn Off hybrid sleep (plugged in)**

**But unfortunately, with all these efforts, after I reboot my machine, the hibernation file always shows up again.**

So how can I **permanently** disable hibernation?

I am using DELL Vostro 3670. Do I need to modify BIOS?

### ADD 1 - 12:43 PM 2/13/2019

This is how I fix my Wake-On-LAN issue.

After I follow the above link to solve the hibernation file recreation issue, my wake-on-lan still doesn't **fully** work.

I can wake my computer with a magic packet sending tool **only shortly after** my computer go to sleep. If the computer sleeps for long, it cannot be waken.

I then downloaded the [latest Real GBE network card driver](https://realtek-download.com/realtek-pcie-gbe-family-controller/). And follow [here](https://www.currentware.com/faqs/wake-on-lan/) to set it up. It suddenly works. **It can even work without a magic packet sending tool.** I just connect my computer with the remote desktop (mstsc). And then the computer wakes up.

### ADD 2 - 12:49 PM 2/13/2019

It turns out enabling hibernation doesn't block the Wake-On-LAN. I re-enabled the hibernation with `powercfg /h on`. And then explicitly let the machine hibernate. And still, the remote desktop can wake it up.

Comment: I am 95% sure hybrid sleep requires you to enable hibernation